# My Upgrade Plans

Tags: road-bike, vintage

About that Nishiki Sport, here are my plans for it:

Phase 1:

1. Upgrade wheels to 700c from 27".  I already have them.
2. Upgrade brakes to accommodate different size wheels.
3. Modify to 7-speed cassette (replacement wheels are spline).

Phase 2:

1. Considering upgrade to 11-speed cassette.

Comment: Can you please add details as to what you want to achieve and why you have made the above decisions?

Comment: Hi, you've posted this as a question- do you have a question?  If this is important information for your other question, you may edit that question- if it's just for fun, you might find someone who wants to chat in the [chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=bicycles.stackexchange.com).  This is meant to be a Q+A site rather than a discussion board.

Comment: This doesn't really fit with the Q&A format.   Consider joining [chat] which is more free-form discussion.   I'm upvoting this purely so you have the 20 rep to enter chat.

Comment: What Nishki Sport? Please make your questions and answers stand on their own.

Comment: I added this into your other question. you can edit your question yourself. Editing it will bump it to the top of the queue on the site.